# Finding the most prevalent alphabet in a string

Tags: python

> Given a word consisting of uppercase and lowercase letters, write a
> program to determine the most frequently used alphabet in the word.
> However, the program should not distinguish between uppercase and
> lowercase letters.
>
> **Input**: The input consists of a single line containing a word consisting of uppercase and lowercase letters. The length of the word
> will not exceed 1,000,000.
>
> **Output**: Print the most frequently used alphabet in the word as an uppercase letter on a single line. However, if there are multiple
> alphabets that are used equally as the most frequent, print "?"
> instead.
>
> For example, if the input is zZAa the result would be ?  and if the
> input is ZzA, the result would be Z

This is the code I made

```
listAlphabet =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
listNumber = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

word = list(input().lower())

for i in range(0,len(word)):
    for j in range(0,26):
        if word[i] == listAlphabet[j]:
            listNumber[j] = listNumber[j]+1

maxnumber = max(listNumber)
if listNumber.count(maxnumber)>=2 :
         print('?')
else:
    print(listAlphabet[listNumber.index(maxnumber)].upper())
```

I believe there is a much easier way, so I want to learn an efficient way. I did manually type all the alphabets

I tried the program and it worked fine, just looking for a new way to solve it.

Comment: Since your code works fine, consider asking for improvements on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Was this translated by AI? The usage of "alphabet" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Kelly, I've seen this elsewhere (India, I think?) where "alphabet" is used to mean a _letter_ (rather than the usual meaning of _the set of letters in a language_).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the collections package. This will return a dictionary with each unique character and the number of times it occurs. From there we can look up the item with the largest count. For example

```
import collections

list_text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZab"

char_dict = collections.Counter(list_text.lower())

max_val = max(char_dict.values())
max_chars = [key for key,val in char_dict.items() if val == max_val]

print(f"Char(s) '{max_chars}' is/was found {max_val} times.")

# Char(s) '['a', 'b']' is/was found 3 times.
```

Comment: Since you're already using `collections.Counter`, consider using its [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method

Comment: What about ties?

Comment: Updated code, now handles ties.

Comment: Handles it incorrectly, though.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, good point. You should post an answer with that. That's a good one.

Comment: Actually it's also wrong without ties. Output should just be the letter.

Comment: There isn't a significant difference from your answer to post another. I'd rather prod you to edit yours to use all relevant features of the builtin that you're recommending :)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Is most_common actually helpful here? How would you use it?

Comment: @KellyBundy `most_common(2)` gives the two most common items. If both have the same value, output `?`, else output the first key

Comment: @Jesse, you should probably mention why you've violated the output format requirement from the question.  It specifically says you should print a single character plus newline.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can get a string containing all lowercase letters by importing `ascii_lowercase` from the `string` module. In terms of efficiency, the most obvious change would be to remove one of the loops. One approach would be to use a dictionary to store the letters and their frequencies (starting at 0), like this:

```
#Dictionary will look like this on initialisation
#{
#    'a': 0,
#    'b': 0,
#    ...
#}

from string import ascii_lowercase

letter_frequencies = { letter: 0 for letter in ascii_lowercase }
```

Then you could loop over each letter in the word, and increase the frequency of each letter that you find by 1.

```
word = input().lower()

for letter in word:
    letter_frequencies[letter] += 1
```

Then we can grab the highest frequency, search through the dictionary key value pairs and record every key who's value is equal to the highest frequency.

```
max_frequency = max(letter_frequencies.values())

most_frequent_letters = [l for l, f in letter_frequencies.items() if f == max_frequency]

if len(most_frequent_letters) > 1:
    print('?')
else:
    print(most_frequent_letter[0])
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav, typed this out on mobile and copied that from the post.

Answer (score 0):

My logic will give output in single iteration, i.e. O(n). We can use dictionary to store frequency. I am creating keys for only available letters in word, not for unavailable letters.

```
word=input().upper()
aplhabetDict={}
maxFreq=0
maxLetter="?"
for letter in word:
    if letter not in aplhabetDict.keys():
        aplhabetDict[letter]=0
    aplhabetDict[letter]+=1
    if maxFreq==aplhabetDict[letter]:
        maxLetter="?"
    elif maxFreq<aplhabetDict[letter]:
        maxFreq=aplhabetDict[letter]
        maxLetter=letter
print(maxLetter)
```

1. We will iterate over word using for loop.
2. If any letter is unavailable, initialize it with 0.
3. We will increase counter/frequency of current letter by 1.
4. If frequency of current letter is equal to max frequency, it means we have multiple letters with max frequency. So we will set maxLeter as "?".
5. Else if frequency of current letter is greater than max frequency, we will update values of frequency of current letter as maxFreq and current letter as maxLetter.
6. Else, frequency of current letter is less than max frequency. We can ignore current letter.
7. Print value of maxLetter as output.

My test cases and output are following:

```
aZzA => ?
ZzA => Z
aZzabjkabjkZa => A
aZzabjkabjkZaz => ?
aZzabjkabjkZazZ => Z
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way:

```
from statistics import multimode

word = input().upper()
modes = multimode(word)
print(modes[0] if len(modes) == 1 else '?')
```

Or:

```
from statistics import multimode

word = input().upper()
mode, *others = multimode(word)
print(mode if not others else '?')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution works well, but you're right that there's a more efficient and concise way to solve this problem using Python. You can use a dictionary to keep track of the frequency of each alphabet letter without distinguishing between uppercase and lowercase letters. Here's an optimized version of your program:

```
word = input().lower()
word = input().lower()
letter_counts = {}
for letter in word:
  if letter.isalpha():
    letter_counts[letter] = letter_counts.get(letter, 0) + 1
max_count = max(letter_counts.values())
most_frequent_letters = [letter for letter, count in letter_counts.items() if count == max_count]
if len(most_frequent_letters) > 1:
   print('?')
else:
   print(most_frequent_letters[0].upper())
```

This code eliminates the need for separate lists for alphabets and their counts by using a dictionary. It also efficiently handles the case where multiple letters have the same maximum frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Counter class's most_common function after feeding the Counter with the lowercase letters of the string:

```
from collections import Counter

def prevalet(s):
    (c,count),*more = Counter(filter(str.isalpha,s.lower())).most_common(2)
    return "?" if more and count == more[0][1] else c.upper()

print(prevalet("ZzA")) # Z
```